# multiple node js app with different domain in same vps

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, server

I have a Digitalocean VPS and 3 Nodejs (ExpressJs) application. Now I started all of them in same IP and different port like this:
- 95.5.5.8:65001
- 95.5.5.8:65002
- 95.5.5.8:65003

But now I want when anybody writes app1.com, the first app 95.5.5.8:65000 shows to him like this:

- app1.com  -> load server in port 65001
- app2.com  -> load server in port 65002
- app3.com  -> load server in port 65003

All of the applications are in same VPS by the same IP, How can I do this, please?

Comment: you need to setup domains to point to vps and Nginx as reverse proxy to express applications  there are many guides for this from digital ocean.

Comment: Could you give me a link?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this feature by following steps:

1. In domain setting page, map `app1.com`, `app2.com` and `app3.com` to `95.5.5.8`.
2. In Nginx, configure 3 proxies for `app1.com`, `app2.com` and `app3.com` in directory `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`. Here is the proxy file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/app1.conf` for `app1.com`:

   ```
   server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  app1.com;
       access_log   /var/log/nginx/app1_access.log;
       charset utf-8;

       location / {
           proxy_pass      http://95.5.5.8:65001;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Restart Nginx.

Comment: @SamiAlMorshedi is your problem solved? If yes, maybe you can "accept" this answer?